# Model not updated due to validation error

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have been fighting with an "invisible" error.
I am trying to do what I see as a simple update of a field, however the field never gets updated. Strangely, Yii2 doesn't output any error except for the following log:

> info  yii\db\ActiveRecord::update Model not updated due to validation error.

Code in controler:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $scenario = (Yii::$app->user->identity->technology == $id) ? "updateOwner" : "updateGuest";

        $model->scenario = $scenario;
        $function = $scenario."Technology";

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && Technology::$function($model)) {
            return  $this->render(['view', 'model' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render($scenario, [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The function in model:

```
public function updateGuestTechnology($model){
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
         try 
            {   
                $technology = Technology::findOne($model->id);
                $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

                $technology->scenario = "updateGuest";
                $technology->bno_coins += $model->bno_coins;
                $technology->bots += $model->bots;
                $technology->save();

                //The user query works just fine.
                $user->scenario = "update";
                $user->bots -= $model->bots;
                $user->bno_coins -= $model->bno_coins;
                $user->save();

                $transaction->commit();
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                $transaction->rollBack();
                Yii::error("Error during technology update by owner transaction. UserID: {$buyer->id}");
                return false; //Transaction failed
            }
            Yii::info("Technology updated by non-owner! Technology ID: {$technology->id} . UserID: {$user->id}");
            return true;
    }
```

Scenario:

```
"updateGuest" => ["bno_coins", "bots"],
```

Rules for `bno_coins` and `bots`:

```
//bno_coins rules
["bno_coins", "required", "on" => ["create", "updateOwner", "updateGuest"]],
["bno_coins", "integer", "min" => 0, "max" => Yii::$app->user->identity->bno_coins, "on" => ["create", "updateOwner", "updateGuest"]],

//bots rules
["bots", "required", "on" => ["create", "updateOwner", "updateGuest"]],
["bots", "integer", "min" => 0, "max" => Yii::$app->user->identity->bots, "on" => ["create", "updateOwner", "updateGuest"]],
```

`$model->errors;` Doesn't contain any data. It seems that the whole `$model` doesn't contain any values (that would explain why the validation fails). However, according to Yii Debugger, the requests contain all necessary information.

Comment: did you change the code? as you have Technology::$function($model) so a static function but declaring it without being static. or does it fail before that anyway?

Comment: Today I decided to take further look into this. And... it worked without me doing a single change in the code... Now I am really confused.